# Dagger provide a dependency that depends on the view of the activity

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-architecture-components

I have an activity with the navigation drawer and a lot of fragments in it. I use Navigation library from the Architecture Components. In every fragment I have to write `navController = Navigation.findNavController(activity!!, R.id.fragment_container)`. I want to get rid of this boilerplate code. So I decide to inject it with Dagger.

```
@Module
class MainActivityModule {
    @ActivityScope
    @Provides
    fun provideNavController(activity: MainActivity): NavController {
        return Navigation.findNavController(activity, R.id.fragment_container)
    }
}

@Suppress("unused")
@Module
abstract class ActivityBuildersModule {
    @ActivityScope
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(
            modules = [MainActivityModule::class, MainActivityFragmentBuildersModule::class])
    abstract fun contributeMainActivity(): MainActivity
}
```

Injection into fragments works fine, but when I try to inject into activity application crashes:

```
09-19 19:22:37.152 22342-22342/com.dmitrysimakov.gymlab
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.dmitrysimakov.gymlab, PID: 22342
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
    ComponentInfo{com.dmitrysimakov.gymlab/com.dmitrysimakov.gymlab.MainActivity}:
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ID does not reference a View inside this Activity
    .....
```

So I have to duplicate `navController = Navigation.findNavController(activity!!, R.id.fragment_container)` in the activity. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Can you share what you did for this? Currently, I've initialized navController in my BaseFragment & using it in all fragments. but I want to use it in ViewModels also using Injection. Is it ok to use navigation in ViewModels? How can I achieve that?

Comment: @akshaybhange Don’t let ViewModels know about Android framework classes. Read [this article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/viewmodels-and-livedata-patterns-antipatterns-21efaef74a54) for more details.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, Can you share how can I set TextWatcher to my EditText? It is a part of the android framework and I was using Textwatcher from ViewModel itself but I'm not able to find any good tutorial on it.

Comment: @akshaybhange Set up TextWatcher inside your fragment and handle viewModel's data inside TextWatcher's methods.

Comment: @akshaybhange I have [something](https://github.com/DmitriySimakov/Kilogram/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/dmitrysimakov/kilogram/ui/common/choose_exercise/ChooseExerciseFragment.kt) similar, but with OnQueryTextListener
`searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
                //...
                override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean{
                    viewModel.setSearchText(newText)
                    return true
                }
            })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App crash from activity because when `provideNavController` is called you haven't set your content view yet using `setContentView`

step 1: If your extending `DaggerAppCompatActivity` copy its code and extends AppCompatActivity instead otherwise just do step 2.

step 2: move `AndroidInjection.inject(this)` line from `onCreate` method after`setContentView(...)`

But take care in my experience this may lead to other problems like [this](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/598) so for getting you nav controller from your activity the best choise may be just use an extension, and actually there is a built in one if you have `'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:1.0.0-alpha05'` dependency in your build.gradle:

```
findNavController(R.id.fragment_container)
```

So for your activity you may use this extension and anyway if you're using single activity recommanded way, in most case you'll get navigation from a fragment and there you may still use dagger injection

Comment: Thank you @SamuelEminet. I didn't know about these extension. The same one is for fragments. So I no longer need to use Dagger for this.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to me is to inject the Fragments in `onAttach` and provide the `NavController` **lazily**.

I think the accepted solution is not quite well, as delaying the injection to 
`setContentView` is dangerous: when navigating back and forth that Fragment, `setContentView` will be called again to recreate the view hierarchy. 
If the Fragment needs to observe `ViewModels` or repositories, it will need to be injected. Hence, we will need to to delay observing the ViewModel until `setContentView`, which may end up to the `Fragment` observing the `ViewModel` with multiple subscriptions, which may cause bugs.

Indeed, it is recommended to inject the `Fragments` in `onAttach` : https://dagger.dev/android#when-to-inject

> DaggerActivity calls AndroidInjection.inject() immediately in
>   onCreate(), before calling super.onCreate(), and DaggerFragment does
>   the same in onAttach().

I answered this in https://stackoverflow.com/a/60061872/789110