# injecting viewmodel with navigation-graph scope: NavController is not available before onCreate()

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-viewmodel, android-architecture-navigation, fragment-lifecycle

I'm using a navigation-component in my application and also using shared ViewModel between multiple fragments that are in the same graph. Now I want to instantiate the ViewModel with this graph scope with [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#share_ui-related_data_between_destinations_with_viewmodel).

As you know, in fragments [we should inject objects ( ViewModel,..etc ) in `onAttach`](https://dagger.dev/android#when-to-inject):

but when I want to do this (injecting ViewModel with a graph scope in `onAttach`), this error occurs:

```
IllegalStateException: NavController is not available before onCreate()
```

Do you know how I can do this?

Comment: are you using NavController in onStart()?

Comment: not in `onStart()`. I used NavController to get navGraph's viewModelStore in `onAttach()` @MohammedRampurawala

Comment: You need to used NavController after the onCreate() is called. That means your activity view is initialized.

Comment: Technically you can also do it inside `onCreate` instead of `onAttach`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In short, you could provide the `ViewModel` lazily with dagger `Provider` or `Lazy`.

The long explanation is:

Your injections points are correct. According to `https://dagger.dev/android#when-to-inject`

> DaggerActivity calls AndroidInjection.inject() immediately in
>   onCreate(), before calling super.onCreate(), and DaggerFragment does
>   the same in onAttach().

The problem is some kind of race condition between when Android recreates the `Activity` and the `Fragments` attached to the `FragmentManger` and when the `NavController` can be provided. More specifically:

1. one `Activity` that has `Fragments` attached is destroyed by the OS (can be reproduced with "don't keep Activities" from "developer settings")
2. user navigates back to the `Activity`, OS proceeds to recreate the `Activity`
3. `Activity` calls `setContentView` while being recreated.
4. This causes the `Fragments` in the `FragmentManager` to be reattached, which involve calling `Fragment#onAttach`
5. The `Fragment` is injected in `Fragment#onAttach`
6. Dagger tries to provide the `NavController`

BUT you cannot get the `NavController` from the `Activity` by this point, as `Activity#onCreate` has not finished yet and you get

```
IllegalStateException: NavController is not available before onCreate()
```

The solution I found is to inject provide the `NavCotroller` or things that depend on the `NavController` (such as the `ViewModel`, because Android needs the `NavController` to get nav-scoped `VideModels`) lazily. This can be done in two ways:

- with `Lazy`
- with `Provided`

(REF: https://proandroiddev.com/dagger-2-part-three-new-possibilities-3daff12f7ebf)

ie: inject the `ViewModel` to the `Fragment` or implementation of navigator like this:

```
    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModel: Provider<ViewModel>
```

then use it like this:

```
viewModel.get().events.observe(this) {....}
```

Now, the `ViewModel` can by provided by Dagger like:

```
    @Provides
    fun provideViewModel(
        fragment: Fragment,
        argumentId: Int
    ): CreateMyViewModel {

        val viewModel: CreateMyViewModel
                by fragment.navGraphViewModels(R.id.nested_graph_id)

        return viewModel
    }
```

Dagger won't try to resolve the provisioning when the `Fragment` is injected, but when it's used, hence, the race condition will be solved.

I really hate not being able to use my viewModels directly and need to use `Provider`, but it's the only workaround I see to solve this issue, which I'm sure it was an oversight by Google (I don't blame them, as keeping track of the absurd lifecycle of Fragment and Activities is so difficult).

Comment: Hey, noobie to dagger here. how can I provide fragment? I am using     `@ContributesAndroidInjector
abstract fun contributeDetailFragment(): DetailsFragment`

right now

Answer (score 1):

> ...we should inject objects ( ViewModel,..etc ) in onAttach...

Looks like it is currently a no go for such injection with the original `by navGraphViewModels(R.id.nav_graph)` delegated property provided by `androidx.navigation` package because from the source code

[`findNavController().getBackStackEntry(navGraphId)`](http://navigation/navigation-fragment-ktx/src/main/java/androidx/navigation/NavGraphViewModelLazy.kt%20-%20platform/frameworks/support%20-%20Git%20at%20Google) and

[`public final NavController getNavController()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/navigation/navigation-fragment/src/main/java/androidx/navigation/fragment/NavHostFragment.java?source=post_page---------------------------%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F&autodive=0%2F#171) it stated that:

> ```
>  * Returns the {@link NavController navigation controller} for this navigation host.
>  * This method will return null until this host fragment's {@link #onCreate(Bundle)}
> ```

And here are some workarounds:

https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/issues/442